# Why do i get appcfg.sh: permission denied when i try to download my app from google app engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, bulkloader, bulk-load

I am using google app engine with java. In my web.xml i added following code:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now when i write following command:

```
 /Users/araz68/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4/bin/appcfg.sh download_data --config_file=config.yml --filename=data.csv --kind=Greeting --url=http://myappid.appspot.com/remote_api --application=myappid
```

and i get following text in command prompt:

```
  -bash:/Users/araz68/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.4/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.4/bin/appcfg.sh: Permission denied
```

Can anybody please tell me why permission is denied. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the developer who uploaded the application? Java applications can be downloaded only by the user who uploaded it: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application